# Slick ddl create table order with foreign key dependency on other tables

Tags: scala, slick

I am using [Slick code generator](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/code-generation.html). with Postgresql. slick generates

```
lazy val ddl = table1.ddl ++ table2.ddl ++ table3.ddl ++ table4.ddl
```

Now writing a `beforeEach()`

```
 override def beforeEach() {
    testdb withSession { implicit session =>
      ddl.drop
      ddl.create
 }
```

In running `ddl` it throws sql exceptions due to it trying to create tables which have foreign key on other tables which aren't yet created. how do you run slick created `ddl` to get away with this issue? I would imagine this to be a common situation of how you use `ddl` in slick

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @cvogt : just added `Postgresql` into the question

Comment: Sounds like a Slick limitation. Please open a ticket: https://github.com/slick/slick

Comment: @cvogt : done here : https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/993

Answer (score 0):

Quoting @szeiger "Foreign keys are only created after all tables have been created, so everything should work. I'll need a snippet to reproduce this issue."

So this is a bug. We need a snippet reproducing the problem in order to investigate it. See https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/993

Comment: I should create a standalone sample code and share on the issue link.